# Extract apps with latest versions from file

Tags: java, file, collections

There is a file which contains Apps names with their multiple version:(v1,v2,v3)Need to print only files with the latest version (v3) with appname.

File Contents:

```
MailApp AuthenticationAPI v6
Videoapp CallAppAPI v7  
MailApp DataStorageAPI v10
Videoapp DataStorageAPI v11
MailApp AuthenticationAPI v11
ChatApp DataStorageAPI v2  
ChatApp  DataStorageAPI v3
```

I wrote the below code:

```
public class FileProblem {

    public void readFile() {
        try {
            File file = new File("D:\\cucumber\\Versions.txt");
            BufferedReader fos = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String sCurrentLine;
            int i =0;
            String temp;

            ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
            //List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            Iterator<String> itr = ar.iterator();
            while ((sCurrentLine = fos.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arr = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
                Map<String, String> hs = new TreeMap<String, String>();
                //hs.put(arr[0], arr[2]);
                hs.put(arr[0],arr[2]);

                if(arr.length == 4) {
                    System.out.println("arr[3] = " + arr[3]);
                }
                Iterator<Entry<String, String>> itr1 = hs.entrySet().iterator();

                while(itr1.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(itr1.next());
                }
            }   
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FileProblem fp = new FileProblem();
        fp.readFile();
    }
}
```

But I am stuck on sorting the HashMap by values as it  contains Strings with number.Please help

Comment: please format your file content as in the original one

Comment: @Ruslan Updated file content

Comment: I've just updated the answer

Comment: does the answer make sense?

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for your reply.I was trying to compile the program and am getting an error.Also I am on java 7 so i am trying to make it work,Updated Java version to 8 now.Error: the method maxBy is undefined

Comment: Also imported import java.util.stream.Collectors; 
import java.util.stream.Stream;

Comment: just add static import `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;`

Comment: Thank you!works Perfectly.Although I was thinking is there a more simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file does not have any digits except version number, you can create you own comparator like this:

```
Comparator<String> versionComparator = 
    Comparator.comparingDouble(s -> Double.valueOf(s.replaceAll("\\D+", "")));
```

`replaceAll("\\D+", "")` allows you to get rid of any non number symbols from string.

Next to get latest version of each application use `collect` from java 8 :

```
Map<String, Optional<String>> map = Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH_TO_FILE))
    .collect(groupingBy(s -> s.split(" ")[0], maxBy(versionComparator)));
```

And now just print it

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(value.orElse("Not Found")));
```